# Moving data files failing

Tags: windows-sbs

Trying to migrate data from `C:` to `D:` via the SBS console is failing.

The wizard starts running but drops out in the first few seconds.

I'll post the full logs, but the important lines appear to be as follows:

> An exception of type 'Type: System.IO.FileNotFoundException, mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' has
>   occurred.
>
> Message: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070002)  Stack: at
>   TaskScheduler.TaskSchedulerClass.GetFolder(String Path)  at
>   Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Common.WindowsTaskScheduler..ctor(String
>   taskPath, String taskName)
>
> BaseException:
>   Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.Common.StorageException:
>   GetServerBackupTaskStatus: fail to find the task ---> ErrorCode:0

I've been googling for days with no luck.

I have found that `mscorlib` is a component of `.net`, and I've discovered multiple instances of the file in `%windir%`, `%windir%\winsxs`, `%windir%\Microsoft.net`

Anyone come across and fixed this one before?

```
---------------------------------------------------------
[1516] 110315.190856.1105: Storage: Initializing...C:\Program Files\Windows Small Business Server\Bin\MoveData.exe
[1516] 110315.190856.2875: Storage: Data Store to be moved: Exchange
[1516] 110315.190856.5305: TaskScheduler: Exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
[1516] 110315.190856.5605: Exception:
---------------------------------------
An exception of type 'Type: System.IO.FileNotFoundException, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' has occurred.
Timestamp: 03/15/2011 19:08:56
Message: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
Stack:    at TaskScheduler.TaskSchedulerClass.GetFolder(String Path)
      at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Common.WindowsTaskScheduler..ctor(String taskPath, String taskName)
[1516] 110315.190856.5625: Storage: Exception Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Common.WindowsTaskSchedulerException:
[1516] 110315.190856.5635: Exception:
---------------------------------------
[b]An exception of type 'Type: Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Common.WindowsTaskSchedulerException, Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' has occurred.[/b]
Timestamp: 03/15/2011 19:08:56
Message: Failed to find the task path
Stack:    at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Common.WindowsTaskScheduler..ctor(String taskPath, String taskName)
      at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.Common.ServerBackupUtility.GetServerBackupTaskStatus()
---------------------------------------
An exception of type 'Type: System.IO.FileNotFoundException, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' has occurred.
Timestamp: 03/15/2011 19:08:56
Message: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
Stack:    at TaskScheduler.TaskSchedulerClass.GetFolder(String Path)
      at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Common.WindowsTaskScheduler..ctor(String taskPath, String taskName)
[1516] 110315.190856.5665: Storage: Error Retrieving Server Backup Task Status: ErrorCode:0
BaseException: Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.Common.StorageException: GetServerBackupTaskStatus: fail to find the task ---> ErrorCode:0
BaseException: Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Common.WindowsTaskSchedulerException: Failed to find the task path ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
  at TaskScheduler.TaskSchedulerClass.GetFolder(String Path)
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Common.WindowsTaskScheduler..ctor(String taskPath, String taskName)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Common.WindowsTaskScheduler..ctor(String taskPath, String taskName)
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.Common.ServerBackupUtility.GetServerBackupTaskStatus()
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.Common.ServerBackupUtility.GetServerBackupTaskStatus()
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.MoveData.Helper.get_ServerBackupTaskState()
[1516] 110315.190857.6216: Storage: Backup Task State: Unknown
[1516] 110315.190857.9347: Storage: Launching the Move Data Wizard!
[1516] 110315.190857.9397: Wizard: Admin:QueryNextPage(null) = Storage.MoveDataWizard.GettingStartedPage
[1516] 110315.190857.9417: Wizard: TOC Storage.MoveDataWizard.GettingStartedPage is on ExpectedPath
[1516] 110315.190857.9577: Wizard: Storage.MoveDataWizard.GettingStartedPage entered
[1516] 110315.190857.9657: Wizard: Admin:QueryNextPage(Storage.MoveDataWizard.GettingStartedPage) = Storage.MoveDataWizard.DiagnoseDataStorePage
[1516] 110315.190857.9657: Wizard: TOC Storage.MoveDataWizard.DiagnoseDataStorePage is on ExpectedPath
[1516] 110315.190857.9657: Wizard: Admin:QueryNextPage(Storage.MoveDataWizard.DiagnoseDataStorePage) = Storage.MoveDataWizard.NewDataStoreLocationPage
[1516] 110315.190857.9657: Wizard: TOC Storage.MoveDataWizard.NewDataStoreLocationPage is on ExpectedPath
[1516] 110315.190857.9657: Wizard: Admin:QueryNextPage(Storage.MoveDataWizard.NewDataStoreLocationPage) = null
[1516] 110315.190857.9697: Wizard: ----------------------------------
[1516] 110315.190857.9697: Wizard: The pages visted:
[1516] 110315.190857.9697: Wizard: Current Page := [TOC Storage.MoveDataWizard.GettingStartedPage]
[1516] 110315.190857.9697: Wizard: [TOC]        : TOC Storage.MoveDataWizard.DiagnoseDataStorePage
[1516] 110315.190857.9697: Wizard: [TOC]        : TOC Storage.MoveDataWizard.NewDataStoreLocationPage
[1516] 110315.190857.9697: Wizard: Step 1 of 3
[1516] 110315.190907.0406: Wizard: Admin:QueryNextPage(Storage.MoveDataWizard.GettingStartedPage) = Storage.MoveDataWizard.DiagnoseDataStorePage
[1516] 110315.190907.0416: Wizard: Storage.MoveDataWizard.GettingStartedPage exited with the button: Next
[1516] 110315.190907.0416: WizardChainEngine Next Clicked: Going to page {0}.: Storage.MoveDataWizard.DiagnoseDataStorePage
[1516] 110315.190907.0496: Wizard: Storage.MoveDataWizard.DiagnoseDataStorePage entered
[1516] 110315.190907.0606: Wizard: Admin:QueryNextPage(Storage.MoveDataWizard.DiagnoseDataStorePage) = Storage.MoveDataWizard.NewDataStoreLocationPage
[1516] 110315.190907.0606: Wizard: Admin:QueryNextPage(Storage.MoveDataWizard.NewDataStoreLocationPage) = null
[1516] 110315.190907.0606: Wizard: ----------------------------------
[1516] 110315.190907.0606: Wizard: The pages visted:
[1516] 110315.190907.0606: Wizard: [TOC] visited: TOC Storage.MoveDataWizard.GettingStartedPage
[1516] 110315.190907.0606: Wizard: Current Page := [TOC Storage.MoveDataWizard.DiagnoseDataStorePage]
[1516] 110315.190907.0616: Wizard: [TOC]        : TOC Storage.MoveDataWizard.NewDataStoreLocationPage
[1516] 110315.190907.0616: Wizard: Step 2 of 3
[19772] 110315.190907.0656: Storage: Starting System Diagnosis
[19772] 110315.190907.0656: Storage: Getting Data Store Information
[19772] 110315.190907.1086: Storage: Create the list of storage and DB directory path
[19772] 110315.190907.1246: Messaging: Begin Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingTasks..ctor
[19772] 110315.190907.1546: Messaging: Begin Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingTasks.Initialize
[19772] 110315.190907.1596: Messaging: Begin Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingRunspace.Initialize
[19772] 110315.190907.1606: Messaging: Exchange install path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\bin
[19772] 110315.190908.4157: Messaging: E12 Monad runspace created ID: Microsoft.PowerShell
[19772] 110315.190908.4237: Messaging: Begin Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingRunspace.StaticExecute
[19772] 110315.190908.4287: Messaging: Executed management shell command: get-exchangeserver
[19772] 110315.190910.2369: Messaging: End Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingRunspace.StaticExecute
[19772] 110315.190910.2369: Messaging: End Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingRunspace.Initialize
[19772] 110315.190910.5699: Messaging: Begin Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingTasks.GatherAdminInfo
[19772] 110315.190910.5699: Messaging: Begin Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingRunspace.StaticExecute
[19772] 110315.190910.5719: Messaging: Executed management shell command: get-user -Identity "dmagroup.local\Administrator"
[19772] 110315.190911.0870: Messaging: End Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingRunspace.StaticExecute
[19772] 110315.190911.0880: Messaging: Begin Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingRunspace.StaticExecute
[19772] 110315.190911.0880: Messaging: Executed management shell command: get-mailbox -Identity "d2ae2bf0-48a7-4ce9-9e72-bb3c765454ac"
[19772] 110315.190911.1300: Messaging: End Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingRunspace.StaticExecute
[19772] 110315.190911.1310: Messaging: User Administrator is mail enabled and can use MessagingManagement to send mail.
[19772] 110315.190911.1310: Messaging: Email address used for user: administrator@dmagroup.co.uk
[19772] 110315.190911.1440: Messaging: Begin Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingRunspace.StaticExecute
[19772] 110315.190911.1440: Messaging: Executed management shell command: get-group -Identity "Domain Admins"
[19772] 110315.190911.1630: Messaging: End Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingRunspace.StaticExecute
[19772] 110315.190911.1640: Messaging: User Administrator is a member of Domain Admins and can use MessagingManagement to manage Exchange.
[19772] 110315.190911.1640: Messaging: End Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingTasks.GatherAdminInfo
[19772] 110315.190911.1640: Messaging: MessagingManagement enabled for Exchange management: True
[19772] 110315.190911.1640: Messaging: MessagingManagement enabled for mail submission: True
[19772] 110315.190911.1640: Messaging: End Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingTasks.Initialize
[19772] 110315.190911.1640: Messaging: End Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Tasks.TaskMoveExchangeData.CreateDataStoreDriveList
[19772] 110315.190911.1670: Messaging: Begin Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingRunspace.Initialize
[19772] 110315.190911.1670: Messaging: Begin Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingRunspace.StaticExecute
[19772] 110315.190911.1670: Messaging: Executed management shell command: get-storagegroup -Server "SERVER01"
[19772] 110315.190911.2990: Messaging: End Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingRunspace.StaticExecute
[19772] 110315.190911.3070: Messaging: Begin Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingRunspace.Initialize
[19772] 110315.190911.3070: Messaging: Begin Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingRunspace.StaticExecute
[19772] 110315.190911.3070: Messaging: Executed management shell command: get-mailboxdatabase -Server "SERVER01"
[19772] 110315.190911.4440: Messaging: End Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingRunspace.StaticExecute
[19772] 110315.190911.4520: Messaging: Begin Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingRunspace.Initialize
[19772] 110315.190911.4520: Messaging: Begin Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingRunspace.StaticExecute
[19772] 110315.190911.4520: Messaging: Executed management shell command: get-publicfolderdatabase -Server "SERVER01"
[19772] 110315.190911.5240: Messaging: End Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Messaging.Management.MessagingRunspace.StaticExecute
[19772] 110315.190911.5510: Storage: Data Store Drive/s Details:Name=C:\,Size=12675712420
[19772] 110315.190911.5510: Storage: Data Store Size Details: Current Total Size=12675712420  Required Size=12675712420
[19772] 110315.190911.5510: Storage: MoveData Task can move the Data Store=True
[19772] 110315.190911.8401: Storage: An error was encountered when performing system diagnosis : ErrorCode:0
BaseException: Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.Common.StorageException: WMI error occurred while accessing drive ---> System.Management.ManagementException: Not found
  at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
  at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.Common.DriveUtil.IsDriveRemovable(String drive)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.Common.DriveUtil.IsDriveRemovable(String drive)
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.Common.DataStoreInfo.LoadAvailableDrives()
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.Common.MoveDataUtil.CanMoveData(DataStoreInfo storeInfo, MoveDataError& error)
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.MoveData.DiagnoseDataStorePagePresenter.DiagnoseDataStore(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
[1516] 110315.190912.0331: Storage: An error occured during the execution: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> ErrorCode:0
BaseException: Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.Common.StorageException: Diagnosing the Data Store failed (see the inner exception) ---> ErrorCode:0
BaseException: Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.Common.StorageException: WMI error occurred while accessing drive ---> System.Management.ManagementException: Not found
  at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
  at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.Common.DriveUtil.IsDriveRemovable(String drive)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.Common.DriveUtil.IsDriveRemovable(String drive)
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.Common.DataStoreInfo.LoadAvailableDrives()
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.Common.MoveDataUtil.CanMoveData(DataStoreInfo storeInfo, MoveDataError& error)
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.MoveData.DiagnoseDataStorePagePresenter.DiagnoseDataStore(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
  at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.MoveData.DiagnoseDataStorePagePresenter.backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
  at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Common.Wizards.Framework.WizardFrameView.Create()
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Common.Wizards.Framework.WizardChainEngine.Launch()
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.MoveData.MainClass.LaunchMoveDataWizard()
  at Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.Storage.MoveData.MainClass.Main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it was a drive mapped using the `subst` command causing the provblem.

To disable, open `CMD` and type in `subst [drive] /d`

To remap afterwards type `subst [drive] [path]`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's start at the top. First of all, your analysis about the file is correct, but it won't help you.

`mscorlib.dll` is the core library of the .NET framework. It is where the `FileNotFoundException` is implemented. The error message does **not** indicate that there is an issue with `mscorlib.dll`.

The `FileNotFoundException` is *thrown* because the program you were using (the migration wizard) tried to access that file that simply did not exist.

However, at this point I am uncertain if that is even an issue here, as the log simply goes on. So either, it ignored the error (which leads to the following errors) or it is simply non-critical. Nevertheless, let's take a brief look.

### Stage 1

At the start of your log, 3 exceptions are being thrown. All stack traces and exception descriptions sound like the wizard is enumerating your Windows Server Backup tasks in task scheduler (SBS uses Task Scheduler to set up Backup tasks). During this process of parsing the backup tasks, it tries to get access to a folder (possibly the backup target location) and that folder does not exist. Thus, the error in the log.

The wizard treats these exception as non-critical, which can be deduced from the fact that it kept writing to the log and this line, that indicates that an *unknown* state is an expected outcome of the process:

> [1516] 110315.190857.6216: Storage: Backup Task State: Unknown

So, an error happened, and the state could not be determined. Let's move on.

### Stage 3

This is where the next issue happens. The final, fatal one that will cause the wizard to abort.

The key element of this error message is

> WMI error occurred while accessing drive

The wizard will try to get some information on your drive and it will fail at some point.

That error message will yield you much better results on the web. But I would urge you to do the search yourself and judge which results are helpful to you (possibly, your [target disk is a dynamic disk](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/smallbusinessserver/thread/d0b4dd79-1d61-4383-9bb2-2f775975045f/))

Sorry that I couldn't offer you a direct solution, but I hope my analysis will help you in solving the issue. It would be appreciated if you report back and write your own answer if you're able to solve the problem :)

Comment: That's great. Thanks for your help. I'll look more into the drive access failure and report back. Would +rep you but alas I'm not able to as yet!

Comment: I should probably have put these earlier:
it's not a dynamic disk;
although the backup is not implemented through SBS on this server (we use Backup Exec a lot), we did try setting it up, running it, and running the move data wizard to no avail.

Comment: If there's a virtual drive mapped in subst will this cause the movedata wizard to see a dynamic disk and crash out? I'm looking and haven't found anything yet...

Comment: @MilesHayler: I've never used the Move Data wizard myself, so I don't know any solutions to possible problems with it. I would, most likely, try to start to determine why it fails on the Backup task. Either remove all backup tasks that exist or change them so they'll be properly processed. Once that works, move on to the next error.

Comment: Cheers. We're currently looking into a SUBST drive on the machine which could be causing the WMI error (which is very similar to the error you get using dynamic drives). I'll report back when we solve it.

Comment: @MilesHayler: Interesting. If you're able to solve it, I would love to hear about it :) You can also pop into [chat] and discuss your latest findings :) Cheers

Comment: @OliverSalzberg Disabling the subst drive solved it. Apologies for the delay, it's been manic!

Comment: @MilesHayler: Awesome! Please add your own answer explaining the details if you feel that it could benefit others. Cheers :)